# ASP.NET MVC 5 / Dev Extreme HTML Editor Control / Azure Pipeline build partial generation issues?

Tags: azure-devops, asp.net-mvc-5, devexpress

I'm running into a weird issue where we've upgraded our DevExpress to their newest version (23.2.4).

This issue is specifically on their [dxHtmlEditor](https://js.devexpress.com/jQuery/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/HtmlEditor/Getting_Started_with_HtmlEditor/) control.

Here is our code:

```
<div id="contactNoteCreate">
    @{
        var editor = Html.DevExtreme().HtmlEditor()
            .ID("createNoteEditor")
            .Height(400)
            .Placeholder("Add a note about a contact");

        editor.Render();
    }
</div>
```

Whenever we deploy via Azure Dev Ops build/release, then it freezes up when it tries to load the partial in the razor page:

```
<div class="tab-pane active" id="Notes">
      @Html.Partial("~/Areas/HR/Views/Contacts/_ContactNotesPartial.cshtml", Model.ContactNotes)
</div>
```

It is doing this on multiple of the [dxHtmlEditor](https://js.devexpress.com/jQuery/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/HtmlEditor/Getting_Started_with_HtmlEditor/) control.

I've been working with DevExpress support and they have not heard of any other issues. They would like an example (which I'm about to do soon I think), but they still believe it is on our side and not theirs.

Is there anything else I can check on the DevOps build side to see why that partial is not being generated properly?

I do not see any errors in AppInsights either on that slot of our app service.

The actual partial is built out it seems fine in the /bin directory:

[image]

If I publish directly from VS 2022, it works fine (so far).

On our build task, I have verified that VS 2022 is selected:

[image]

Any other thoughts I might try?

Comment: You can try to check the [Agent Specification](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LL1do.png) of the pipeline. For the classic pipeline, it will use the windows-2019 agent by default. Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 is only available in [windows-2022 (windows-latest)](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/ubuntu22/20240204.1/images/windows/Windows2022-Readme.md#visual-studio-enterprise-2022). In the Visual Studio build task , if the preferred VS version cannot be found, the latest version found will be used instead.

Comment: By the way, you can enable the variable [system.debug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to check more detailed logs. You can also configure verbose logs for a single run with the Enable system diagnostics checkbox.

Comment: @MiaoTian-MSFT: I updated with the answer. We figured it out. Thanks for your information.

Comment: Thanks for your update. It is great to hear that you have solved the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue resolved.

The [dxHtmlEditor](https://js.devexpress.com/jQuery/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/HtmlEditor/Getting_Started_with_HtmlEditor/) control uses quill.js. On the upgrade, we had to upgrade the version of quill.js. For some reason the minified version of that will not bundle properly on the Azure Dev Ops pipeline steps.

We remove the quill.min.js from our bundle functionality and then referenced the file directly and everything started to work fine.